# 'double' is not a supported type in ROS messages?

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I meet two issues for the data type delcaration:
Q1: I define the message in the svr file as below--but when I check the srv by rossrv show I got error message like:

unknown srv type... Cannot locate message [double] in package with paths... blablabla..

So I can not define double type data in srv file? instead uint32 works OK.. But ROS should support double , correct?

```
 uint8 Number    #0/1/2/3
 string Name     
 bool  In_Out      #(true) Out(False)
 double TimeStamp       #double??
 double Duration        #double??
 ---
 string Feedback        
 bool PaySucc
```

Q2: In the relevant Server.cpp file, I define a struct data class as below, but this time the IDE (I am using QT creator w/ROS plugin) report that unknow type of "string", and double is support instead..

This really confused me.. is this the QTcreator  issue?
BTW, is there a standard data type roscpp support can refer to?

```
typedef struct Req
{
    uint8_t Number;    //0/1/2/3
    string Name;    
    bool IN_OUT;     //(true) Out(False)
    double TimeStamp;      //double??
    double Duration;       //double??
    /******/
    string Feedback;        
    bool Succ;               //Success(true) Fail (false)


} Req;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323093/%27double%27-is-not-a-supported-type-in-ros-messages?/) by [macleonsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41341/macleonsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For Q1, see #q205541 and the link [to this page](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Fields) therein. In short: in msg/srv definition you need to use `float64` as this is a "ROS built-in type". Those are used to autogenerate the code for different languages. In C++ use `double`.

Q2: this is expected behavior, as you are now using C++. This is, `double` is a C++ primitive type, whereas `string` is not. Use `std::string` instead. No fault with QTCreator there.

---

Edit:

`std::string` is the C++ string type, whereas `std_msgs::String` is the C++ representation of a ROS standard message that only contains a `string` (ROS built-in type) / `std::string` (C++ type) as a field. Check the `std_msgs/String` message definition [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/String.html).

I.e., manipulating the respective `data` field of the `std_msgs::String` with `c_str()` will work.

E.g. (using `std::string`s `empty()` method for sake of brevity)

```
std_msgs::String string_msg;
std::string cpp_string;
cpp_string.empty(); // compiles
string_msg.empty();  // does not compile
string_msg.data.empty(); // compiles
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [macleonsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41341/macleonsh/) on 2019-05-14**:
@mgruhler Thanks so much. This is exactly what I want to find--simple and strightforward..
Yes follow your suggestion I solve the issue quickly..
One additional questions:
What is the difference between std::string  and std_msgs:String? my initial understand is the 1st one is c++ type and 2nd one is ROS override type? but looks not that simple.
Some small experience that I can manipulate std::string by using c_str() but can not do that to std_msgs:String..

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-05-14**:
@macleonsh edited answer above.

If you feel this is answering your question, please mark the answer as correct by clicking the check-mark next to it.